# Add specific column c# datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, oracle11g, datagridviewcolumn

i have create  a table suppliers1`create table suppliers1(

```
>  sup_id NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY,  sup_name VARCHAR2(40),  sup_address
> varchar2(50),  sup_phone NUMBER(15))
```

;

and insert values
`

```
> INSERT  INTO suppliers1 (SUP_ID,SUP_NAME,SUP_ADDRESS,SUP_PHONE) VALUES
> (100,'PPS','Bds',99545414); INSERT  INTO suppliers1
> (SUP_ID,SUP_NAME,SUP_ADDRESS,SUP_PHONE) VALUES
> (200,'Abcd','Dhaka',0295469); INSERT  INTO suppliers1
> (SUP_ID,SUP_NAME,SUP_ADDRESS,SUP_PHONE) VALUES
> (300,'Xyz','Ctg',0896547556);
```

i have load data using following command

```
>  OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM
> suppliers1", con);
>             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>             adp.Fill(dt);
>             dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

but i want to add specific column programmatically  such as sup_id, or sup_name etc, i have try the code but fail how can it's possible ?

> `String testValue2 = (String)dataGridView1["sup_id", 4]value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the simple code

> ```
>  OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM suppliers1", con);
>             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>             adp.Fill(dt);
>             dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
>             dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;// you can add more
>             dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Sup Id";
>             dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "sup_id";
>             dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Sup Name";
>             dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "sup_name";
>             dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
datagridView1.Columns.Add(...)
```

There are several options, most simple for making string columns is just to supply the name. You can also supply a type, or you can create a DataGridViewColumn instance and pass that in, for most flexibility

Here's the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i  have trying and  i am fail , can you explain please